# Excel365 VBA Compile Error on Mac for Generating Outlook Events - 'A Project or Library Cannot be Found'

Tags: excel, vba, macos, events, outlook

I'm trying to automatically generate outlook events using Excel VBA (on Excel v16.68 or VBA 7.1).  The same code works perfectly on Windows OS but encountering 'A Project or Library Cannot be Found' error on 'OutApp As Outlook.Application' when tried on Mac OS for following line:

```
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application, OutEvent As Outlook.AppointmentItem
```

Any suggestions on resolving the error or an alternative?

Thanks!

Any suggestions on resolving the error or an alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

VBA is only supported for Excel, Power Point, and Word under Office for Mac. Outlook is not exposed.